# Using Jquery Autocomplete with C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I am new to webdev, Jquery and asp.NET, I have tried to follow other's questions, and have been working on this problem for about a week now. I cannot seem to get it work with my database.

I am trying to implement a simple autocomplete feature for a text box on my asp.NET webpage using Jquery, C#, and a SQL database. So far I have a  C# function "Search()" which grabs the results similar to a local string. However I currently don't know how to pass the input text to this C# function.

Here is my .cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> results;
    //ListBox1.Items.Clear();
    results = OleDb.fDbReadToArray(@"SELECT Project_Name from tProjectNames where Project_Name like '" + Local_String_to_be_passed from asp.NET + "%'");
   //foreach (string item in results)
   //{
   //    ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
   //}
}
```

From what I've read online a good way to achieve this would to use Jquery and ajax to post the users input from the text box to my c# code and then get the results. I am trying to follow the Jquery example for autocomplete with a remote data source 
(see https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote).

But I am struggling to make the Jquery go to my c# function. Here is my asp.NET:

```
<html lang="en">


 <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(function () {
              $("#ProjectNames").autocomplete({
                  source: "live_search.aspx.cs/Search()",
                  select: function (event, ui) {
                      log("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id);
                  }
              });
          });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
      <label for="ProjectNames">Project Names: </label>
      <input id="ProjectNames" type ="text" oninput="Search()" />
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me how to get what the user types in the input text box go to my C# function and then post the results back to the Jquery suggestion box?

Thank you

EDIT:
Here is the solution that ended up working for me, credit Chetan Ranpariya.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $(function () {
              $("#ProjectNames").autocomplete({
                  source: function (request, response) {
                      var objdata = JSON.stringify({
                          obj: {
                              query: $("#ProjectNames").val()
                          }

                      });
                      $.ajax({
                          url: "Live_Search1.aspx/Search",
                          data: objdata,
                          type: "POST",
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                          success: function (data) {
                              response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                  return {
                                      label: item,
                                      value: item
                                  }
                              }))
                          }
                      });
                  }
              });
          });
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
         <div>
              <asp:label for="ProjectNames" runat="server">Project Names: </asp:label>
              <input ID="ProjectNames" type ="text" runat="server" />
         </div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.cs:

```
    public class Myobj
{
    public string query { get; set; }
}


[System.Web.Services.WebMethod] 
public static List<string> Search(Myobj obj)
{

    List<string> projectList = new List<string>() { "project", "sam", "daniel" };
    List<string> results = new List<string>() { };
    foreach(string project in projectList)
    {
        if(project.Contains(obj.query))
        {
            results.Add(project);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

If anybody has any edit's on how this can be improved computationally please let me know, keep in mind that project List will probably grow to be in the thousands. Thanks again Chetan Ranpariya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a static web method in the code behind of the page and then you can call it from Client side by using url `{yourpage}.aspx/{yourmethod}`. And it also should return data which you can capture in client side and use it.

So the `Search` method should be created as following. Here `Search` method does not accept any parameter.
I am returning list of searched string values from this method which will be captured as JSON at the client side which I can use whatever way I want to.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> Search()
{
    List<string> results;
    //ListBox1.Items.Clear();
    results = OleDb.fDbReadToArray(@"SELECT Project_Name from tProjectNames where Project_Name like '" + Local_String_to_be_passed from asp.NET + "%'");

    //foreach (string item in results)
    //{
    //    ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
    //}
    return results;
}
```

And you call the method from JQuery as following.

```
$(function () {
    $("#ProjectNames").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var objdata = {

            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "live_search.aspx/Search",
                data: JSON.stringify(objdata),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        //item here is a string value coming from server.
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Hello Chetan, after declaring my C# method as a static web method as you suggested, I am still unable to call this method from the Jquery. I tried debugging by setting a break point  in my Search method but it never gets hit. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to use fiddler and see what happens when you AJAX call is made to the web method?

Comment: No I haven't and I can't use fiddler

Comment: Without being able to debug or to know what happens when AJAX call is made to `WebMethod` there is very little I can do to help you. You can use developer toolbar of Google Chrome or IE and see in network tab what is being returned from Web Method. At least you should be able to see the HttpStatus code there. Try debugging javascript to see if actually hits autocomplete code or not.

Comment: I just noticed one error in my solution. I corrected it. I corrected the url and made the WebMethod `public static`. Try the updated code and use developer toolbar to see if it hits the URL and what is being returned from the server. Apologies for the incorrect code..

Comment: I think I know the problem, after using the google developer tool, I am getting a 404 b/c  it is looking for a url which has my search query appended to it in the form: live_search.aspx.cs/Search?term=Query which doesnt exist. I still don't know how to fix this though because I can't change the directory which this file is located on the fly and I am testing locally. Thoughts?'

Comment: @TeeseCaprice I feel very bad about the solution I posted originally. It was having lot of bugs. I have updated my answer above with tested and working code. You will have to change it as per your requirement. Let me know if you still face any problem with this.

Comment: I applaud you good sir after using your code and chromes developer tools I was able to get my code to work. I have posted my working code in my edit. Thank you